# Force SSL for hosting

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an angular app hosted on Parse.com using their Javascript SDK. I want to force the users to access via SSL.

I have no actual cloud code other than the documentation suggested code to redirect to SSL.

cloud/main.js

```
require('cloud/app.js');
```

cloud/app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());

app.listen();
```

When I nav to http://myapp.parseapp.com index.html is delivered and no redirect is made.

I could write some javascript to redirect but users could opt out of it so its not really a solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that `public/index.html` exists and is served statically by the web server. Your express code isn't being run because this file exists on the file system.

If you go to http://myapp.parseapp.com/some-page-doesnt-exist.html however then you'll be redirected to HTTPS because the request is passed to your express code.

The solution is to delete `public/index.html` and to have all HTTP requests go through express. Then you can serve `index.html` using express.

https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp

Comment: Okay,  I moved index.html to somethingelse.html and added a redirect in express and this has the desired effect.

Comment: updated answer to have the actual code for solution.